# Why return std::ranges::safe_iterator_t instead of std::ranges::safe_subrange_t from algorithms taking std::ranges::output_range

Tags: c++, iterator, range, c++20

I'm writing an algorithm that writes some data to provided output range (initial text of the question included the specifics and that turned discussion in comments into a wrong direction). I want it to be as close as possible in API to other ranges algorithms in the standard library.

I've looked at the latest draft for instances of `std::ranges::output_range` and found only 2 algorithms:

- [std::ranges::fill](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.fill)
- [std::ranges::generate](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.generate)

And they both return `std::ranges::safe_iterator_t`. I thought it is logical to return `std::ranges::safe_subrange_t` instead. Even if you write to output stream, you can still return an iterator-sentinel pair in that case and pass that range down the line.

I've found [P0970](https://wg21.link/p0970) and it looks like `std::ranges::safe_subrange_t` was added later. Maybe the algorithms were simply not updated? Or is there a different reason?

Comment: What is a "Unicode scalar value"?

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit https://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html#unicode_scalar_value

Comment: How does that differ from a sequence of code units then? What sort of conversion are you envisioning?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Added my code so far.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Should I drop Unicode stuff and replace it with "algorithm that writes something to output range"? Because specific algorithm doesn't matter much. All it matters is that I write stuff and I thought that returning range is more logical than returning single iterator.

Comment: @Lyberta: "*I thought it is logical to return `std::ranges::safe_subrange_t` instead.*" Why is that logical? What subrange would it return? Why should the range-based interface be so different from the iterator interface?

Comment: @NicolBolas so you can pipe it to other algorithms via `operator|` and such and also keep the resulting range for other stuff.

Comment: @Lyberta: Algorithms don't work by `operator|`. That is a fundamentally different feature, managed by range-actions and such... which are *not* part of the Ranges TS. They may eventually be standardized, but they're not part of C++20.

Comment: @NicolBolas They don't _now_ - but they certainly can't in the future if the range-based algorithms don't return ranges.

Comment: @Barry: But they aren't *supposed to*. If you look at Ranges v3, the range algorithm version of `sort` is a different function from the composable action version of `sort`. They're different because they're different kinds of things. One is a simple algorithm, and the other is a composition action. Also, because composible actions are lazily evaluated, while the algorithm versions are not.

Comment: @NicolBolas They're not different kinds of things at all? They do exactly the same thing -- the algorithm just returns the end iterator while the action returns the range. Composible actions also aren't lazily evaluated, they're eager.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The presence of `safe_iterator_t` in the ranges design can be attributed to two things:

1. Some algorithms return iterators into the range(s) passed into the algorithm, and
2. Some ranges have iterators than can outlive their ranges, and some don't.

For (2), an example might be `std::string_view`. Iterators into the string view are still ok to use even after the `string_view` object itself has been destroyed. That is because a `string_view` is just referring to elements elsewhere in memory, and the `string_view` object itself contains no extra additional state. Counter-examples would be any of the containers; e.g., `std::vector`, which owns its elements, and many of the views in C++20's `std::ranges` namespace, most of which contain additional state (`views::filter`'s predicate, for instance).

Taking the two bullets above together, now consider a function like `find` (simiplifying):

```cpp
template <input_range R, class T>
  requires ...
safe_iterator_t<R> find(R && rg, const T & val);
```

This function returns an iterator into the range `rg`, but if `rg` is an rvalue, then it will probably get deleted when the function returns. That means the returned iterator is almost certainly dangling.

`safe_iterator_t` checks to see if `R` is one of those special range type for which the iterators can safely outlive the range. If so, you just get the iterator back, no muss no fuss. If not, then this function returns an empty object of a special type named `std::ranges::dangling`. That is intended to clue you in to the fact that you need to be thinking more deeply about lifetime here.

The same logic holds for algorithms that take output ranges, like `ranges::fill` and `ranges::generate`.

So why not return `safe_subrange_t` instead of `safe_iterator_t`, you might ask? Wouldn't that make the algorithm compose nicely with other algorithms?

*It would!* But it would be returning to the caller information they already have; namely, the position of the end of the range. In the algorithms, we avoid doing needless work to make them as efficient as possible. Given ABIs and calling conventions, returning a pointer (e.g., the found position) is more efficient than returning a struct containing two pointers (e.g., the found position and the end of the range).

Rather, we use higher-level views (and actions, in range-v3) for composing multiple operations concisely.

Comment: Why isn’t it simply fails to compile if owning temporary is passed?

Comment: Good question. You're right, in the case of `find` that's probably a better answer. There are other algorithms that return several pieces of information, and in that case `safe_iterator_t` is used to redact just the dangly bits.

We could have decided to treat algorithms that return _just_ a `safe_iterator_t` differently from ones that return a struct with a dangly member, but nobody argued for that, so here we are.

Comment: I guess, attempt to use `dangling` in place of a normal iterator will fail to compile so there will be a compilation error anyway, just further from the broken place in the code.